# opencv undefined reference for CvSVM::predict(CvMat * const)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have encountered a strange problem about OpenCV 2.4.6.1.
The code is from http://www.opencv.jp/sample/svm.html.
I have link the project with

```
     -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_optim
```

But it still has errors as follows:

```
      undefined reference to `CvSVM::predict(CvMat const*) const'
      collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have test with OpenCV 2.4.0 and OpenCV 2.4.5, both with these errors.

Could someone give me some advice, please? Thanks.

Comment: You might be missing libraries or have some problem with the order of them in the command line. Do you have `pkg-config` on your system? It might be able to tell you what your linker options should be.

Comment: @us2012, Thanks. I have test with it, but the error still exists.                                 INCLUDEPATH += `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS += `pkg-config --libs opencv`

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks the answer.   http://answers.opencv.org/question/21522/opencv-undefined-reference-cvsvmpredict-maybe-it/